# Iframe in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, firefox, iframe

I have an MVC app running inside an iframe of an aspx page. The reason being is that i needed to be able to use the sites master page. I keep receiving the following error from firefox `"The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it"`. Is this because the doctype needs to be specified for the iframe? The top of my cshtml page looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

my aspx page looks like this

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/CATSMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CATS.aspx.cs" Inherits="Cats.CATS.Cats.MoreCats" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="CatsContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <iframe style="height:1080px;width:975px;" src='<%= Request.Url.Scheme + System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host +
(Request.Url.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + Request.Url.Port) + "/Mvc/Cats/MoreCats" %>'></iframe>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptPlaceHolder" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

How can i correct this error and declare the doctype for the iframe specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the declaration below as the first line of the `<head>` section of the page displayed in the iFrame

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```